# how can I trans this {'person': {'name': 'cc', 'age': 12} } to {'person.name': 'cc', 'person.age': 12}?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

like this, I have a object:

```
{
  'person': {
    'like': {
      'color': 'red',
      'food': 'rice'
    },
    'name': {
      'first': {
        'word': 'bob',
        'num': 4
      }
    },
    'age': {
      'next': 18,
      'now': 19
    }
  }
}
```

I want to trans it to this:

```
{
 'person.like.color': 'red',
 'person.like.food': 'rice',
 'name.first.word': 'bob',
 'name.first.num':4,
 ....
}
```

how can I trans it? 
this is three nest, If I have five nest or more? how can I do this?

Comment: Your array is not valid.

Comment: If these answers helped you, accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

An array like the one you want can't happen, but you can get a similar object with this:

```
var newObj = {};
var temp = {};

for (var a in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
    temp = p[a];
    for (var b in p[a]) {
      if (p[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        newObj[a + "." + b] = temp[b];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check the output:

http://jsbin.com/cutudovala/edit?js,console

Comment: @ Dave Gomez   if I have five layer?

Comment: First of all you didn't asked for five, and second you can easily reuse that code to work with as many objects you want.

Comment: You don't have to, the first for loop should iterate through all the persons. Just try it and make the fixes if they are need it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will flatten a nested object any number of levels deep, containing objects or plain values.

```
function flatten_to_dots(o) {
  var result = {};

  function _flatten(o, prefix) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
      var value = o[k];
      if (value && typeof value === 'object') _flatten(value, prefix + k + '.');
      else result[prefix + k] = value;
    });
   }

   _flatten(o, '');

   return result;
}
```

The internal function `_flatten` loops over the keys of an object. If the corresponding value is a scalar, it is simply placed in the result. If it is an object, we call `_flatten` recursively to process its properties, passing along the prefix we want to use for its keys.

```
> flatten_to_dots({'person': {'name': 'cc', 'age': 12 }})
< {person.name: "cc", person.age: 12}

> flatten_to_dots({person: { name: {first: 'Joe', last: 'Blow'}, age: 12}})
< {person.name.first: "Joe", person.name.last: "Blow", person.age: 12}
```